# for loop not iterating through all increments

Tags: java, loops, file-io, iteration, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program for a lab task at uni, the code will make is fairly obvious what is does, but when it asks for the first line, ie number one 1 in the loop, and you insert a string and hit enter, it automatically jumps straight to the last increment in the loop (5) any ideas?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class limmerickWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

        Scanner limScan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner to read user input

        System.out.println("please enter the name of the file");

        String fileName; 

        fileName = limScan.next(); //filename for the text file 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))); //declaring a new file writer

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //loop to get 5 seperate lines from the user
        {
            System.out.println("please enter line " + i );

            out.println(limScan.next()); //writes the contents of the scanner to the file

        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? The code looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE so it debugs automatically before compiling

Comment: No, it doesn't. "Debugging" means running your code in a debugger, or attaching a debugger to your application.

Comment: Though the question is probably answered now you should be aware that debugging doesnt mean to report compilation errors but to execute an application step by step through the use of a debugger (try to click on the left side in eclipse at the text editor and run the application with the "bug" symbol ;) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While reading with `scanner.next()` white space gets used as default delimiter. Which means that if your file name is inserted with several words separated by spaces,they will be read with continuous `next()` call first.

**For example**, while reading the `filename` using `scanner.next()`, if you insert:

`test ATest BTest CTest DTest ETest`

And hit `Enter`, you will see that a file with name `test` gets created in your relevant class path, containing text data `ATest BTest CTest DTest ETest`.

Try using `nextLine()` instead inside the for loop.